# com.sun.net.httpserver no puedo montar certificado SSL

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas,

Actualmente tengo un aplicación construida en PHP, Codeigniter y Jquery. Pero una parte especifica me vi forzado en construir una aplicación Java que el usuario debe descargar en su computador personal para un tema especifico, la información capturada por este .jar la publico a través del paquete com.sun.net.httpserver de java y la muestro en el navegador por el puerto que sea requerido accedo a esta página con http://127.0.0.7/servicio y desde la versión de pruebas de la aplicación no tengo problemas en adquirir los datos con la función $.get de Jquery, el problema me surge en con el aplicativo que esta detrás de un https ya que la seguridad de los navegadores actuales impiden que desde una pagina https se acceda a un http, para el dominio de localhost he generado un un dominio real, algo igual a lo que hace la url [lvh.me](http://lvh.me/) la cual siempre que se accede apunta es a localhost, e incluso generé un certificado para utilizar el https el cual lo monto en mi maquina de trabajo (Apache, linux), en el pc de un amigo (Apache, Windows) y en mi servidor de trabajo (IIS, windows) y me indica la conexión segura al sitio en cuestion.

Mi problema es que para agregar el certificado en un archivo .jks, que es la forma en la que generalmente se lee el archivo en una aplicación en .jar, me establece la conexión https, pero esta me indica que no es segura ya que no se reconoce la información del emisor del certificado.

Será que alguien me puede orientar en como fusionar los archivos .crt y .key en un archivo .jks sin que me quede esta falla de verificación ?

Mi anterior archivo .jks lo generé con esta [guía](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/06/13/how-to-keystore-creating-jks-file-from-existing-private-key-and-certificate/)

Muestras de las conexiones generadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por razones de confidencialidad no puedo agregar información del dominio, la información referente sobre el certificado se la puedo exponer como imagen cubriendo información sobre el dominio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La misma página que utilice para generar el certificado original, tiene la opción de unir el certificado .crt y el archivo .key que uno genera y entrega un certificado p12 luego de eso, generé el archivo jks con:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore localhost.jks -srckeystore joined_cert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

La página que utilice para generar el certificado inicialmente fue https://startssl.com en ella se pueden generar certificados SSL gratuitos para luego ser utilizados en nuestros propios servidores. (Apache, IIS, etc)

[image: Certificado Validado]

Comment: Si el último párrafo es considerado como spam, favor comentar y será removido